# Interrupt a thread in DatagramSocket.receive

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm building an application that listens on both TCP and UDP, and I've run into some trouble with my shutdown mechanism. When I call `Thread.interrupt()` on each of the listening threads, the TCP thread is interrupted from listening, whereas the UDP listener isn't. To be specific, the TCP thread uses `ServerSocket.accept()`, which simply returns (without actually connecting). Whereas the UDP thread uses `DatagramSocket.receive()`, and doesn't exit that method.

Is this an issue in my JRE, my OS, or should I just switch to `(Datagram)Socket.close()`?

UPDATE: I've found an [analysis](http://www.thatsjava.com/java-essentials/14879/) of the problem. It confirms that the behavior is not consistent.

Comment: Just to help anyone else dealing with the same issue: My `ServerSocket.accept()` wasn't returning without connecting. It was returning because my browser (FF4b10) requests the favicon 3 times. One of the requests was tripping the Thread.interrupted() check.I'll be switching over to using `close()`.

Comment: link is dead, could you update with a new one?

Comment: Wayback machine doesn't have that specific article, and I don't remember the exact title. The gist is that you'd expect the behavior of `ServerSocket` to match `DatagramSocket` more or less, but they handle interruptions/socket closure differently.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A common idiom for interrupting network IO is to close the channel.  That would be a good bet if you need to effectively interrupt it while its waiting on sending or receiving.

```
public class InterruptableUDPThread extends Thread{

   private final DatagramSocket socket;

   public InterruptableUDPThread(DatagramSocket socket){
      this.socket = socket;
   }
   @Override
   public void interrupt(){
     super.interrupt();  
     this.socket.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have worded it better myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, `close()` is the proper way to interrupt a blocked socket.  Interrupting and keeping open something that may have already done a partial read or write makes things unnecessarily complex.   It's easier to only have to deal with a "success" or "give up" result.

Answer (score 0):

`DatagramSocket.receive` blocks until it receives a datagram. Probably what you need to do is use `setSoTimeout` to make it timeout.

Comment: Timeout is not an acceptable solution in this case. Also, `DatagramSocket.receive()` should be interrupted, which is why this is weird.

Comment: @SEK: no it shouldn't. There is nothing in the Javadoc that says so. If you want interruptible behaviour you need to use DatagramChannel, which implements InterruptibleChannel.